# Xaml: Finding a control defined within ControlTemplate from C# at ResourceDictionary level

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

`Library.xaml`

```
 <ResourceDictionary>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="test" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Button  Width="200"  Height="40"  Name="my_custom_btn"   Click="r_Click_1"  Style="{StaticResource button_style}">Button</Button>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I want to access this Button element defined within my **ControlTemplate** from my C# file **when template is not applied** in `Main.xaml`.

I have tried all methods
`Template.FindName`, `Application.Current.Resource`, `Control.GetTemplateChild()`, `using VISUALTREE HELPER` search but i am not getting this element in my c# code.

As far as I know these methods are used to find elements when a control template which is defined somewhere in `Library.xaml` is loaded in `Main.xaml` file by giving its TargetType.
But what if this template is not applied and Still I want to access its element from my code.

I have looking for a proper solution for a past few days. plz help!!
Please explain it fully as I am new to WPF..

Comment: If the `Template` is not applied you cannot access control from within that template. You can only get item from `Template` via control which uses that template. Why do you need this `Button`?

Comment: @dkozl Actually I am building `UI library` and I am want to access any Button or any Controls defined within a `ControlTemplate` so that i can change its Background or some other properties when needed on run time.

Comment: If you want to *change its Background or some other properties when needed on run time*, then do it at run time when the `ControlTemplate`s have been applied.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this problem?